# Why is my laptop's wireless Internet connection slow?

Tags: networking, wireless, performance

I'm sitting on the same level as my wireless router but still the internet is acting pretty slow.

```
PING any-fp.wa1.b.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=13.0 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=3 ttl=55 time=14.7 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=5 ttl=55 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=6 ttl=55 time=13.7 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=7 ttl=55 time=34.4 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.re1.yahoo.com (69.147.125.65): icmp_req=9 ttl=55 time=13.5 ms
```

Following are results from SpeedTest - even though speeds seem to be fine, the download test took over 5 minutes...

```
Last Result:
Download Speed: 6714 kbps (839.3 KB/sec transfer rate)
Upload Speed: 4069 kbps (508.6 KB/sec transfer rate)
```

Is there a way to "Flush" the connections on  ubuntu and start over again? I think I've been noticing this problem eversince I came back from another country where I had to create a DSL  wired connection to get access to the internet.  Also, ever since then when I try to connect to ethernet (wired) It doesn't work.

Is there a way to get everything back to default.

Answer (score 2):

I had some severe issues with my Atheros based wireless card in my Acer laptop.  It was fine in 10.10, but 11.04 was horrible. the command:

```
sudo -s

echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

fixed it for me.  [Others](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746326) have [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/linux/+bug/735171) the same issue with the ATH9k driver