# How to troubleshoot a slow wireless connection (step by step)?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, performance

I am looking for a standard approach to troubleshooting slow wireless connections, regardless of what card or wireless router you have. Pings to the gw in a simple network less than 10 ft away should yield 1-2ms max.

Not the case here.

What are the first steps anyone would start to troubleshoot this slowness?

Considering I have the best newest laptop and best newest wirelss router in the world, and the top rated best newest wireless card onboard my laptop.

What would you do first?

Please list in this format:

1. yadda..
2. more stuff...
3. ...more yadda stuff

I will not bore you with what I have tried; I have done the basics, but maybe I can learn something new. So I am open for a simple how-to.

I am using amd64 10.04 LTS.

Here is an example ping I am experiencing:

```
ping 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=59.4 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=186 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=115 ms
^C
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.358/93.823/186.334/64.251 ms
```

---

its been great hearing 1 response, very cool info, i just added more input to persuade you/those viewing that I have done some basics, to assist in response to my quest for a step by step approach to completion.

as for the "garbled pastes, welp, the interface didnt allow me much room to edit it, ex: when i hit the enter key to create a new paragraph, it took that as i was done. so the input methods defined in this page needs a little more tuning i would suggest.

lastly, i am still experiencing slow speeds/varied speeds. therefore I would like more input, possibly from new individuals, second opinions are always welcomed as there are hundreds of cmd utils i have yet to explore for this issue. i can say it might be the frames in ifconfig possible as culprit and documentation points to drivers, as yes, these are broadcom restricted drivers. any wizards about?

i would like to hear from you all, and wish to use this procedure on help.ubuntu as somepoint giving credit where it is due.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is my internet slow on ubuntu laptop wireless](http://askubuntu.com/questions/52736/why-is-my-internet-slow-on-ubuntu-laptop-wireless)

Answer (score 8):

1. Check the wireless connection
   `iwconfig` is the tool for displaying and setting parameters for your wireless card. Below is an example showing a connection to "Your Wireless Network".

   ```
   wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Your Wireless Network"  
     Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
     Bit Rate=48 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
     Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
     Encryption key:off
     Power Management:off
     Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
     Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
     Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:161   Missed beacon:0
   ```

   Some important information shown:

   - Bit Rate which is how fast data is transmitted to your wireless router
   - Link Quality which is a ratio of how strong your connection with the router is. A low number (e.g. 10/70) would indicate that you are either in a noisy radio environment or that your computer is too far from the router to receive adequate power.

     - If you suspect interference from other routers, try `iwlist [interface] scanning`, where [interface] is your wireless card's device name to see if there are other routers that are interfering with your router's channel, the frequencies at which your computer and the router transmit.
   - For more information check out `man iwconfig`
2. Check that your network is connected

   ```
   $ ifconfig [interface]

     wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
     inet addr:192.168.1.115  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
     inet6 addr: fe80::6ef0:49ff:fe66:6c18/64 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
     RX packets:8104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:7690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
     RX bytes:5637315 (5.3 MiB)  TX bytes:1698532 (1.6 MiB)
   ```

   Important information shown in the output:

   - Line 3 indicates that your link is "UP"
   - The second line shows your ip address ("inet addr"), the broadcast ("Bcast"), and the netmask.
   - The third line is used only for ipv6
   - Lines 4-6 indicates TCP/UDP packet statistics. If there are alot of dropped packets here and your link quality is high, the problem is most likely not on your system, but on the router's end.
   - Line 7 shows the total number of bits sent and received over the interface
3. Check the routing tables and your connection from the wireless router. I'm not sure this is in the scope of your question, but it's the next logical step.

Comment: Great answer, kudos to you, @overdamped, for giving a detailed answer to a somewhat vague question.

Comment: more info:$ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:4  Signal level:196  Noise level:163
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

Comment: $ iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth1      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:4  Signal level:196  Noise level:163
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0    ping 4.2.2.2
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=182 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=64.5 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=152 ms

4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 64.582/132.340/182.313/43.256 ms   how is this possible?

Comment: ifconfig:   eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:ee:e6:89:57:66  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eee:e6ff:fe89:5766/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:136363 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:32073
          TX packets:92245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:181323532 (181.3 MB)  TX bytes:9969380 (9.9 MB)
          Interrupt:21

Comment: notice the interruprts... 21.. im using the drivers for broadcom associated with what was found - this were extra drivers that ubuntu loaded, should i just go with /etc/network/interfaces and manually? im also using NetworkManager to handle connection

Comment: route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 eth1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1

Comment: notice the high frames... also... 32073

Comment: what can i do to get pings back to 1-5ms??

Comment: iwlist scanning
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: regarding:   
Great answer, kudos to you, @overdamped, for giving a detailed answer to a somewhat vague question. – William 2 hours ago
 
um... how would you word it better?

Comment: at this point, i am concerned with ipconfig frames being so high and rising... where to begin... step by step, this first, then this next, so forth approach. given all i posted so far, that should answer most relevant queries. i await more input if you would be so kind.

Comment: @olyanderson: Everything looks pretty nominal (can't really tell as formatting has garbled your iwconfig). I'm not sure if it's ubuntu. You've posted several pings at this point, but they all have a flaw in that they're to hosts that are external to your local network. I think that the most telling ping that would be indicative of your network would be to your router and would go something along the lines of `ping 192.168.1.1` If those ping's are acceptable, you know the issue exists beyond the router. Beyond your router, i would contact your ISP as it is most likely not ubuntu. Good Luck.

Comment: hello, welp, i guess one could say this ticket has been left alone, why? i don't know. the input was semi helpful, a few cmds i had not used in a while helped a bit, but i have surmized that this is a kernel issue. when rolling back to previous older natty kernels and a different usb wireless nic was used, it worked. the code required in /lib/firmware was available. i still had the slow laggy issue, nothing was resolved, and i feel also that the dri

Comment: ver is proprietary which of course is really the issue. im using the lastest ubuntu provided kernel and back on broadcom internel wireless nic. i guess ill just have to get a new board at somepoint, as the bluetooth features of this dual bc has never been recognized from initial and repeated upgrades and installs to older and newer kernels, i give. ill be back with another pressing question im sure, stay tuned... l8 oly